# Bcrypt illegal argument: number

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm having issues with bcrypt and I'm not sure why. Here is my code for a basic registration route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

// Register
router.post('/register', function(req, res){

  req.checkBody('username', 'Username is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('kingname', 'Kingdom Name is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'E-Mail is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors) {
    res.render('index', {
      errors: errors
    });
  } else {
    var newUser = {
      username: req.body.username,
      kingname: req.body.kingname,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      password2: req.body.password2
    }

  bcrypt.getSalt(10, function(err, salt){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      newUser.password = hash;
      let post = {username: newUser.username, password: newUser.password, email: newUser.email, kingname: newUser.kingname};
      let sql ='INSERT INTO users SET ?';
      let query = db.query(sql, post, function(err, res){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        } else {
        user_id = res.insertID;
        console.log('Last User ID', res.insertID);
        console.log('User registration successful...');
        res.redirect('/');
        }
      });
    });
  });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now the error I'm getting is this:

> ```
> Error: Illegal arguments: number
>     at Object.bcrypt.getSalt (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:339:19)
>     at /home/kogadmin/www/routes/reg.js:30:10
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at /home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>     at Function.process_params (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>     at next (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>     at Function.handle (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
> ```

Which is why I'm a bit confused. The way the error looks is that it is saying the 10 is the illegal argument, which it isn't, I've made sure that the syntax was correct from their documentation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be genSalt not getSalt?

Comment: Thank you :), I kept reading it as genSalt, I re-read that line several times. Such a bad noob coder :P

Answer (score 18):

I'm pretty sure that should be

```
genSalt(10, function() {})
```

Looks like you have a typo :)

Comment: The heck, could have sworn I did that. Like I read over that and kept reading it as genSalt, im such a noob. Thank you!

Comment: No worries!  Sometimes the simplest thing are the hardest bugs to find!

Comment: `genSalt` is too slow

Answer (score -1):

convert password to string and try.It may work.